# How to generate a random normal distribution with specific standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have already used this function :

```
np.random.seed(40)
np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = 10)
```

However, I'm assuming the values should be between 1 and -1 right?
But I'm getting values that are larger than 1 and smaller than -1. How is that possible?

I'm getting this array :

```
array([-0.6075477 , -0.12613641, -0.68460636,  0.92871475, -1.84440103,
       -0.46700242,  2.29249034,  0.48881005,  0.71026699,  1.05553444])
```

You can see there're values like 2.2924 and also -1.8 which is ranges outside the standard deviation

#### Possible solution

I have made this code, is this okay?

```
final_data = []
count = 0
a = 26 # standard deviation
b = 157 # mean

for i in range(2000):
    y = a*np.random.normal(0, 1, 1) + b # equation to multiply by the std and add the mean
    if y <= upper and y >= lower :
        final_data.append(y[0])
        count += 1
        if count > 608:
            break;
```

Where upper and lower are the mean + std and mean - std.
I have first generated a randomly distributed number and then put it in the equation. If the number is between the specific range, then I added it to the list

Comment: Normal distributions are not restricted to `[-1, 1]`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal Distribution does not restrict the range of the values. It just means that 68% of the values will be within 1 standard deviation of the mean; 95% within 2 standard deviation and 99.7% within 3 standard deviations. 
Theoretically you could get any value from - infinty to infinity irrespective of your standard deviation.

Comment: So how can I fix this? How to make it only gives values in the range [-1, 1] ?

Comment: You can reduce your standard deviation even more (0.5,0.3,0.25 etc.). But again, this does NOT mean that you will never get a value outside [-1,1]. There is a chance that you still could but the probability becomes lesser as you decrease your standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous comment and answer:

If you want to draw random numbers from an interval, you must choose a distribution with an upper and lower bound. For example, the uniform distribution puts equal probability on every number between an upper and lower bound. For numpy, you can check it out here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html

Comment: I don't want the uniform numbers, I want it normally distributed but only with std of 1

Comment: Then you will also draw values that are outside -1, 1. The bounds for the normal distribution are +- infinity. As a workaround, you could extend your code to discard any value outside your interval and perhaps draw a new one to replace it. However, the resulting numbers will not follow a normal distribution